# What does the phrase "на зарядку становись!" mean?

Tags: idioms

I believe it is an idiom.  Literally, it means "on charging become" or "charging is on", but I'm looking for a more meaningful translation.  I found the phrase written on the back of a photo of my Russian girlfriend when she was younger (around 30).  She is sitting on a hotel room bed in the photo next to a vase of flowers.

Answer (score 12):

*Зарядка* ,first of all,means *morning exercises* as soon as you get up and there's another meaning *charging* gadgets.Both give power and strength. The whole phrase means *get ready to do morning exercises!* The origin is a song which was popular many years ago.

> На зарядку,на зарядку,
>   На зарядку по порядку становись!

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!   The translations I gave were from Google translate, which I'm sure you know aren't aways accurate...

Comment: My suggestion would be *"Line up for morning exercise"*, it captures the military undertone of this phrase.

Comment: Given that it's on the bad of a photo of a female on a bed next to some flowers, I assume that it has a sexual connotation too.

Comment: I can't read "between the lines".

Comment: @Jeff there are no sexual connotations whatsoever unless you think girl-scouts are sexy. These photos indicate the atmosphere very well http://youtu.be/D9riXNb5_nM (the atmosphere of the totalitarian regime that controls all aspects of its subjects lives including the physical health).

Comment: What are you talking about J.F. Sebastian?  Maybe you should actually read the questions and answers before you comment on them.

Comment: @Jeff if you want me to be notified about your comment; use @ syntax. Obviously, I did read the question and your comment. What are *you* talking about? Have you clicked the link? Your phrase *"на зарядку становись!"* is from the song in the video.

Comment: Oh?  Did I mention the song or the video?  I really don't care about it.  I was talking about something written on a photo.  The other people who answered were kind enough to explain it thoughtfully, and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

"Line up for morning excersise" - phrase also can be used by an adult to gather up some group of children, say, at summer camp or P.E. at school to do those excersises. Can be followed by command "по порядку рассчитайсь" (i.e. based on the calculated order)

Answer (score -2):

It's not only for adults, it is used in gym class by gym teachers to school students. Also, it's a common phrase, that they say on the morning TV, when they show exercises program and 'становись' doesn't mean 'line up', because it is singular and can be said to one person. It means 'stand up' or 'get up', so "На зарядку становись" means "Get up for the morning exercises".